# frame navigation in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a button on a Page, the Page is loaded inside a Frame (WPF).

Button -> Page - > Frame

When I click on the button I want to open another page inside my Frame (main frame)

How can I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the navigationservice provided by WPF.
Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.aspx